# Unwanted backslash added to string when join a list of strings

Tags: string, list, python-3.8, string-parsing

I have the following string:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections '-std=c++0x' -MD -MF bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/sparse_to_dense_op/sparse_to_dense_op.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/sparse_to_dense_op/sparse_to_dense_op.pic.o' -fPIC -DEIGEN_MPL2_ONLY '-DEIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=64' -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin -iquote external/com_google_absl -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/com_google_absl -iquote external/nsync -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/nsync -iquote external/eigen_archive -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/eigen_archive -iquote external/gif -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/gif -iquote external/libjpeg_turbo -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/libjpeg_turbo -iquote external/com_google_protobuf -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf -iquote external/com_googlesource_code_re2 -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/com_googlesource_code_re2 -iquote external/farmhash_archive -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive -iquote external/fft2d -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/fft2d -iquote external/highwayhash -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/highwayhash -iquote external/zlib -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/zlib -isystem external/nsync/public -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/nsync/public -isystem third_party/eigen3/mkl_include -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/third_party/eigen3/mkl_include -isystem external/eigen_archive -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/eigen_archive -isystem external/gif -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/gif -isystem external/com_google_protobuf/src -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src -isystem external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem external/zlib -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/zlib -w -DAUTOLOAD_DYNAMIC_KERNELS '-std=c++17' -DEIGEN_AVOID_STL_ARRAY -Iexternal/gemmlowp -Wno-sign-compare '-ftemplate-depth=900' -fno-exceptions '-DTENSORFLOW_USE_XLA=1' -DINTEL_MKL -msse3 -pthread '-DTENSORFLOW_USE_XLA=1' '-DINTEL_MKL=1' -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__=\"redacted\"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__=\"redacted\"' '-D__TIME__=\"redacted\"' -c tensorflow/core/kernels/sparse_to_dense_op.cc -o bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/sparse_to_dense_op/sparse_to_dense_op.pic.o)"
```

When I split this string based on white space and then join them using the following code:

```
string_new = ' '.join(string_old)
```

The string converts as:

```
-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 \'-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1\' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections \'-std=c++0x\' -MD -MF bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/sparse_to_dense_op/sparse_to_dense_op.pic.d \'-frandom-seed=bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/sparse_to_dense_op/sparse_to_dense_op.pic.o\' -fPIC -DEIGEN_MPL2_ONLY \'-DEIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=64\' -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin -iquote external/com_google_absl -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/com_google_absl -iquote external/nsync -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/nsync -iquote external/eigen_archive -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/eigen_archive -iquote external/gif -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/gif -iquote external/libjpeg_turbo -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/libjpeg_turbo -iquote external/com_google_protobuf -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf -iquote external/com_googlesource_code_re2 -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/com_googlesource_code_re2 -iquote external/farmhash_archive -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive -iquote external/fft2d -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/fft2d -iquote external/highwayhash -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/highwayhash -iquote external/zlib -iquote bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/zlib -isystem external/nsync/public -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/nsync/public -isystem third_party/eigen3/mkl_include -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/third_party/eigen3/mkl_include -isystem external/eigen_archive -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/eigen_archive -isystem external/gif -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/gif -isystem external/com_google_protobuf/src -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/com_google_protobuf/src -isystem external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/farmhash_archive/src -isystem external/zlib -isystem bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/zlib -w -DAUTOLOAD_DYNAMIC_KERNELS \'-std=c++17\' -DEIGEN_AVOID_STL_ARRAY -Iexternal/gemmlowp -Wno-sign-compare \'-ftemplate-depth=900\' -fno-exceptions \'-DTENSORFLOW_USE_XLA=1\' -DINTEL_MKL -msse3 -pthread \'-DTENSORFLOW_USE_XLA=1\' \'-DINTEL_MKL=1\' -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined \'-D__DATE__="redacted"\' \'-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"\' \'-D__TIME__="redacted"\' -c tensorflow/core/kernels/sparse_to_dense_op.cc
```

As you can see, there are multiple backslashes added to the string. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out why I have unwanted backslashes. The reason is that in my list of strings, there are some string items that are in double quotation, when I join those items using white space, and in the joined string, I have backslashes in place of double quotation.

Comment: Please provide the revised version of your code, showing how you changed the double quotation marks, and what the result looked like. Your verbal description is good, but it isn't enough.